# Find volume by shell method

Tags: integration, volume

I am trying to find the volume for the below question using the shell method but I can't get the right answer. can someone give me step by step answer?

$y = x^3, y = 8, x = 0$ about x-axis

what I tried:

$2\pi\int_0^2y(8-y^(3/2))dy$

The answer is $768\pi/7$ but mine isn't even close.

Comment: What is the region being rotated about?

Comment: @randomgirl, x-axis

Comment: Your limits are off and your shell's width is a bit off too. If you draw it you should see the region is bounded below by y=0 and above by y=8 not 2.

Comment: okay got it. what about the width tho?

Comment: The cross-section of one shell is a horizontal line from ____ to _____. What's the length of that line?

Comment: Since the region is rotated about $x$-axis... The shell's width can be found by plotting a random point $(x,y)$ in the region and seeing that the distance from the $y-axis$ aka $x=0$ to that point $(x,y)$ is $x$. $x$ is going to be the shell's width. You are given though that $y=x^3$ So you can solve this for $x$ to figure out what $x$ is in terms of $y$ since our integral is in terms of $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some conventions for disk / washers confused with conventions for shells.

First your limits; y goes from 0 to 8.  If you were doing disks you would say x from 0 to 2.  Next, how high is each shell?  $y=x^{1/3}$

$2\pi\int_0^8y(y^{1/3})dy$

via washers:

$\pi\int_0^2 8^2 - x^6 dx$